# Ruby on rails Call javascript Function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my application.html.erb with the tag h1 and onclick execute **JS** function `greatTutorial()` .

```
## application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dealabs</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <%= render "layouts/navbar" %>
      <h1 onclick="greatTutorial()">Hello World</h1>
        <% if notice %>
          <p class="notice alert alert-info"><%= notice %></p>
        <% end %>
        <% if alert %>
          <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>

        <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my javascript/pack/application.js

```
##javascript/pack/application.js

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

function greatTutorial() {
    alert('Rails Guides are the best');
}
```

I followed multiple ask on that, but nothing work. If I replace my function onclick by h1 `onclick="alert('danger')"` is working fine. But I don't understand why my function `greatTutorial` is undefined (never exist).

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using Rails 6 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround, though.
In **Rails 6** you can change the function signatures from:

```
function myFunction() { ... }
```

to:

```
window.myFunction = function() { ... }
```

So according to your code try this :-

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


window.greatTutorial = function() {
    alert('Rails Guides are the best');
}
```

Comment: Oh ! i search so long time thanks you is work fine !!
Why the function declare like that (function myfunction() {}) not work now ??

Thanks !

Comment: I am not confirmed may be its rails 6 syntax. Last month I was also stuck in same condition so I solved like above after long hit and try method. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `application.js` to `javascript.js` or `main.js`

This is required if you have application.css and application.js inside packs directory. As webpack deals with css files in special way and create .js extensions.

Check out similar issue reported [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1624) for more details.