# Rails 6: execute a JS function after rendering partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

Rails & Javascript beginner here,

On a training project, I made `flash` messages disappear after few seconds using JQuery. A visitor would send AJAX request to add a product to his cart, then a flash partial 'Added to cart' appears and automatically fades out after few seconds.

---

```rb
# application.html.erb

<div id='flash' class='flex-column'>
   <%= render partial: 'shared/flash'  %>
</div>
```

```rb
# shared/_flash.html.erb

<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= display_flash(key, value) %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'custom/flash' %>  
  # this works, but injects the script each times the partial is rendered
<% end %>
```

```rb
# helpers/application_helper.rb

def display_flash(key, value)
  def display_flash(key, value)
    div_class = [flash_class(key), 'text-center fade show alert-dismissible'].join(' ')

    content_tag(:div, class: div_class) do
      content_tag(:p, value) +
      button_tag(class: 'ml-auto close', 'data-dismiss': 'alert', type: 'button') do
        content_tag(:span, '&times;'.html_safe, 'aria-hidden': 'true') +
        content_tag(:span, 'Close', class: 'sr-only')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```js
// app/javascript/packs/custom/flash.js

function closeFlash(){
  let lastAlert = $('#flash .alert:last')

  function fadeFlash() {
    lastAlert.animate( {opacity: 0}, 2000, function() {
      $(this).hide('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove()
      });
    });
  };

  setTimeout(fadeFlash, 2000)
};

closeFlash();
```

The issue with this is that it pollutes my DOM with unnecessary `<script>` tags:
[image: unneeded script tags]

This could be fixed, but is there a suitable way to execute one specific javascript function after rendering a (AJAX) partial ?
In my case, executing `closeFlash()`  located in `packs/custom/flash.js` each time a partial is rendered.

Thanks for your help and your time

---

**EDIT** Solution:

From Amit Patel answer and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147270/ruby-on-rails-call-javascript-function)

```
# app/views/shared/_flash.html.erb

<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= display_flash(key, value) %>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      closeFlash();
    });
  </script>

<% end %>
```

```js
// app/javascript/packs/custom/flash.js

window.closeFlash = function() {
    let lastAlert = $('#flash .alert:last')

    function fadeFlash() {
        lastAlert.animate( {opacity: 0}, 2000, function() {
            $(this).hide('slow', function() {
                $(this).remove()
            });
        });
    };

    setTimeout(fadeFlash, 2000)
};
```

It doesn't inject the whole function but (I believe) the minimal javascript code to call it.

Comment: Flash messages comes from different sources (AJAX requests or not), and I want a generic way to deal with those. I'm not sure I'm clearly understanding your point though. I'm posting additional code

Comment: I believe what's interests you is `create.js.erb` which `.append` a rendering of the flash partial to the concerned `<div>` and the `display_flash` helper that generates HTML. The message content is store in the flash value, whereas the key is used to set the correct CSS class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'custom/flash' %>` to your layout or your application.js` so that it is available across the app.

modify your template like

## application.html.erb

```
<div id='flash' class='flex-column'>
   <%= render partial: 'shared/flash'  %>
   <script>
     $(function(){
       closeFlash();
     });
   </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amit, I'll take your solution as it looks clear.
I believe it should work, but somehow I've got an error `jQuery.Deferred exception: closeFlash is not defined`. Fixing it will teach me more about webpacker I guess !
Thanks again :)

Comment: To make it works I had to place the `<script>` inside my partial, and declare the `closeFlash` function like so: `window.closeFlash = function() { .... }`. It still injects the content of the `<script>` tag, but it's cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

A more recent approach would be to set a Stimulus controller.